# loading docker image fails

Tags: docker, go, io, waitgroup

I am using `golang`, `docker client` to load a docker image in `.tar` format.

```
func loadImageFromTar(cli *client.Client, tarFilePath string) (string, error) {
    // Read tar file
    tarFile, err := os.Open(tarFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to open tar file: %w", err)
    }
    defer tarFile.Close()

    // Create a pipe to stream data between tar reader and Docker client
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()

    // Set up a WaitGroup for synchronization
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    // Load the Docker image in a separate goroutine
    var imageLoadResponse types.ImageLoadResponse
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        imageLoadResponse, err = cli.ImageLoad(context.Background(), pr, false)
        if err != nil {
            err = fmt.Errorf("failed to load Docker image: %w", err)
        }
    }()

    // Read tar file metadata and copy the tar file to the pipe writer in a separate goroutine
    var repoTag string
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer pw.Close()

        tarReader := tar.NewReader(tarFile)

        for {
            header, err := tarReader.Next()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                err = fmt.Errorf("failed to read tar header: %w", err)
                fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
                return
            }

            // Extract the repository and tag from the manifest file
            if header.Name == "manifest.json" {
                data, err := io.ReadAll(tarReader)
                if err != nil {
                    err = fmt.Errorf("failed to read manifest file: %w", err)
                    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
                    return
                }

                var manifest []map[string]interface{}
                err = json.Unmarshal(data, &manifest)
                if err != nil {
                    err = fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal manifest: %w", err)
                    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
                    return
                }

                repoTag = manifest[0]["RepoTags"].([]interface{})[0].(string)
            }

            // Copy the tar file data to the pipe writer
            _, err = io.Copy(pw, tarReader)
            if err != nil {
                err = fmt.Errorf("failed to copy tar data: %w", err)
                fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    // Wait for both goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()

    // Check if any error occurred in the goroutines
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Close the image load response body
    defer imageLoadResponse.Body.Close()

    // Get the image ID
    imageID, err := getImageIDByRepoTag(cli, repoTag)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to get image ID: %w", err)
    }

    return imageID, nil
}
```

// func: getImageIDByRepoTag

```
func getImageIDByRepoTag(cli *client.Client, repoTag string) (string, error) {
    images, err := cli.ImageList(context.Background(), types.ImageListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to list images: %w", err)
    }

    for _, image := range images {
        for _, tag := range image.RepoTags {
            if tag == repoTag {
                return image.ID, nil
            }
        }
    }

    return "", fmt.Errorf("image ID not found for repo tag: %s", repoTag)
}
```

The `getImageIDByRepoTag` always returns `fmt.Errorf("image ID not found for repo tag: %s", repoTag)`.
Also when I run `docker images` I do not see the image being loaded. Looks like the image load is not completing .

In my other code, The docker images load usually takes time although the docker client `cli.ImageLoad` returns immediately. I usually add some 30 seconds wait time before checking for `getImageIDByRepoTag`. Adding a wait time also did not help in this case.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @BurakSerdar . It is always returning  `fmt.Errorf("image ID not found for repo tag: %s", repoTag)`

Comment: Then, trust what it says. See what images the ImageList call returns, and see if what you are looking for is in there.

Comment: the pipe's content is only partially relayed on to the client, causing the `docker` client to reject the image load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues:

- the two goroutines share `err` so some error handling may get lost

  - you should use unique error variables here for each goroutine & inspect both errors after the `wg.Wait()`
- the main issue: you are reading from the `tar` reader to find the manifest file and extract the tag info - which is fine - but upon finding this, you copy the rest of the byte stream to your pipe. You are thus losing a chunk of the byte stream which never reaches the `docker` client

---

To avoid reading the tar byte stream twice, you could use [io.TeeReader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#TeeReader).
This allows you to read the tar archive - to scan for the `manifest` file - but also have this stream written in full elsewhere (i.e. to the `docker` client).

Create the `TeeReader`:

```
tr := io.TeeReader(tarFile, pw)  // reading `tr` will read the tarFile - but simultaneously write to `pw`
```

the image load will now read from this (instead of the pipe):

```
//imageLoadResponse, err = cli.ImageLoad(context.Background(), pr, false)
imageLoadResponse, err = cli.ImageLoad(context.Background(), tr, false)
```

then change your `archive/tar` reader to read from the pipe:

```
//tarReader := tar.NewReader(tarFile) // direct from file
tarReader := tar.NewReader(pr) // read from pipe (indirectly from the file)
```

you can then drop the your `io.Copy` block:

```
// no longer needed:
//
// _, err = io.Copy(pw, tarReader)
//
```

since the tar-inspection code will read the entire stream to EOF.

P.S. you may want to reset the `io.EOF` to `nil` to avoid thinking a `EOF` is a more critical error, when you inspect any potential errors from either of the goroutines:

```
header, err = tarReader.Next()
if err == io.EOF {
    err = nil  //  EOF is a non-fatal error here
    break
}
```

Comment: After modifying as suggested. Image loads as expected.  But  `getImageIDByRepoTag` fails to find the repoTag. It appears that there is slight delay after the `imageLoad`. If I add  `time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)` after `imageLoad` and before `getImageIDByRepoTag`  seems to work fine and returns the imageID. Any alternative to this ?

Comment: I would separate the 2 functions - you can see the image body is closed on function return - but prior to this you are attempting to query the image. There may be a docker client blockage as one request is still pending (since the body has not close) - which may explain the delay.

Comment: I tried separating them. But no luck. I will close this issue as image load is working. and will open a new question regarding the `getImageIDByRepoTag`